# Laravel: ejecucion de artisan con parametros desde controlador

Tags: laravel, artisan

Intento crear programáticamente (desde una acción en un controlador ) un nuevo Controlador de tipo Resource.

En base la ejecución de artisan desde funciones es:

```
Artisan::call('make:controller ',['name'=>$nombrecontrolador]);
```

Pero no logro dar con la forma de agregar la opcion '-- resource' a la llamada. ¿Alguien sabe como?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías pasar el comando completo como un string:

```
Artisan::call("make:controller name $nombrecontrolador --resource");
```

También podrías probar pasándolos como argumentos en el segundo parámetro, asignándole true como valor a dicha opción:

```
Artisan::call('make:controller ', [
    'name' => $nombrecontrolador,
    '--resource' => true
]);
```

Revisa la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: La segunda opción funciono perfecto. Mil gracias @Shaz